# после использования метода importlib.import_module программа зависает и вылетает

Tags: python, pyqt5

Здраствуйте, я пишу одну программу в которой подразумевается то что по нажатию кнопки появляется проводник, выбираешь python файл и программа его выполняет. Но при использовании функции программа зависает и вылетает. Вот тот самый кусочек кода:

```
def file_open(self):
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/пк/Desktop/HelloPioneer",
                                      title="Select a File",
                                      filetypes=(("Python Files",
                                                  "*.py*"),
                                                 ("all files",
                                                  "*.*")))
importlib.import_module(f'{filename}')
```

Comment: Функция import_module принимает на вход название модуля, а не путь к файлу

Comment: спасибо за помощь, помогло